# In Cypress, what is the statement used to check that some number greater than or equal of other number?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, cypress

`expect(allDates[index - 1]).to.be.greaterThan(convertedDate);`
I used this to compare if greater than

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cypress TDD Assertions](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#TDD-Assertions)

There is an *isAtLeast* assertion that would probably fit this.

i.e.

```
assert.isAtLeast(allDates[index-1], convertedDate);
```